# On common repeating expansions of coprime pair?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fractions, decimal-expansion

Let $a,b>0$ be coprime and not divisible by $2$ or $5$.

Now 
$$\frac1a=0.00\dots00r_100\dots00r_100\dots00r_1\dots$$
$$\frac1b=0.00\dots00r_200\dots00r_200\dots00r_2\dots$$

where $r_1$ and $r_2$ are repeating portions of fractions of lengths $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ respectively.

How to show that when we truncate both the sequences at length $\ell_1\ell_2$ and shift the sequences to the left above the decimal point and consider the resulting sequences as integers $m,n$ respectively then we have to have $b|m$ and $a|n$ and is it true $ab|mn$?

Example:

$\frac13=0.333333\dots$ and $\frac1{11}=0.09090909090909090909090909090909\dots$ and $\ell_1=1$ and $\ell_2=2$.

So truncate at $2$ significant positions and shifting left gives $m=33$ and $n=9$ (note there is no leading set of $0$s for $\frac1{11}$ and $r_2=09$. Now $11|m$ with $\frac m{11}=3$ and $3|n$ with $\frac n{3}=3$. $gcd(11,3)=1$ is consistent with what we have.

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  What, for example, does $\dots$ mean?  Are the blocks of $0's$ the same length?  Is it important that that length be $4$?  Are you choosing $a,b$ to have some special property (and if so, what property?) or are you claiming that any $a,b$ would work here.?  Maybe if you worked an example for some specified $a,b$...

Comment: @lulu no different block lengths (it is obvious) for different integers..

Comment: It's not obvious to me.  If the blocks of $0's$ have different lengths, then it doesn't look like your expressions are rational.  If, say, $a=3$, what is $r_1$?

Comment: @lulu $r_1=3$ and there are no $0$s.

Comment: So, then all the blocks of $0's$ have the same length.  So the $\dots$ doesn't mean anything? You just wanted to make the $r_i$ start with something other than $0$?  Please add a complete example to clarify the question.  I suggest using $a=3,b=11$ as (I'm guessing) for $11$ you'd have $r_2=9$ and the blocks of $0's$ all have length $1$.

Comment: @lulu after the first set of $0$'s all further set of $0$s have same length in a given fraction.

Comment: Right, so in your expression the "$\dots$" are wrong (as you've written out four zeroes).  the way you've written it it is impossible for your readers to know if it matters that $a,b$ both have the same length block of zeroes (both of yours have length $4$) or if that is just a careless accident.  Without an example, I think this is hopelessly confusing.

Comment: @lulu anyone who knows fractions knows what context dots mean in query.

Comment: I give up.  Good luck!

Comment: @lulu why? what is unclear? Ok made one change hope it is clear now.

Comment: Enough.  I asked for an example three times and you refused.  I'm done.

Comment: @lulu what is unclear now? you are not answering me.

Comment: @lulu gave example.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot.  I've gotten a bit tied up but will take a look later in the day.   In your example, though, $ab=11\times 3$ which certainly does not divide $\gcd(33,9)$.

Comment: I see the edit.  But obviously $a|n,b|m\implies ab|mn$ so I think you must mean something else.

Comment: @lulu actually think about it $n$ has nothing to do with $a$ then why does $a|n$ (the periods are somehow linked and what is this relationship?)?

Comment: Yes, that part of the question is quite interesting.  It seems obviously false in that $n$ is defined with minimal reference to $a$.  For example, if $\frac 1a=.7777\dots$ then it would be false, but of course $.777\cdots $ is not the reciprocal of an integer.  I suppose one just needs to write everything out, but it looks a bit forbidding.